# How to make a zipfile as password protected

Tags: ios, iphone, zip

Does anyone know a way to make a zipfile password (hard coded) protected with the library ZipArchive?

```
// Add a file to zipfolder
[ziparchive addFileToZip:textPath newname:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", matches[i]]];
```

After above line I have added the line below for the password but it isn't working.

```
[ziparchive UnzipOpenFile:textPath Password:@"123456"];
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this reference in one of my project for zip and unzip: https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive

Use this method:

```
+ (BOOL)createZipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path withContentsOfDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath withPassword:(NSString *)password
```

OR

```
+ (BOOL)createZipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path withContentsOfDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath keepParentDirectory:(BOOL)keepParentDirectory withPassword:(NSString *)password;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I manage to make a file password protected,but when i double tap to unzip  the file,password prompt came again and again when i enetered a right password as well.

Comment: @Dharmesh using [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:sourcePath withContentsOfDirectory:documentsDirectory withPassword:@"12345"]; for password and when i double tap on zipfolder for unzip, it shows the message "Unable to expand folder.zip".